# Meaning of $x^2+y^2=0$ (imaginary can have real property?!)

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

> While working for some homework problems for circle to select the radius for circles, I encountered with radius 0 and centre at origin i.e., $$x^2+y^2=0$$.

When I asked about it to the teacher, he said that it is the equation for point circle and also it denotes the pair of imaginary lines with real intersection point.

*My doubt*

> How come two imaginary lines have real intersection? I mean it's imaginary (pff), it can't be on the paper. How will it have a real intersection point?

Comment: $0$ is both an imaginary number and a real number. A complex number is a number of the form $a+bi$ for real $a,b$. A real number is any complex number where $b=0$. An imaginary number is any complex number where $a=0$. Zero fits the criteria for both of these categories.

Comment: @Mason But if the imaginary lines can't be plotted in real world, how can they have intersection point that we can plot or see?

Comment: Who told you this lie?

Comment: @Mason What do you mean? Imaginary shapes can be plotted?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ is both an imaginary number and a real number. A complex number is a number of the form $a+bi$ for real $a,b$. A real number is any complex number where $b=0$. An imaginary number is any complex number where $a=0$. Zero fits the criteria for both of these categories.

Really the expression "imaginary" is a kind of PR problem for mathematicians. There is nothing so imaginary about imaginary numbers. Moreover... there is nothing so real about real numbers.

Comment: please explain the last two lines of your answer. If possible please give some examples. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: The point $a+bi$ is really a lot like the point $(a,b)$. You are clearly familiar with plotting in the cartesian plane. But now we have the added power that $i^2=-1$. So whenever we take a number in the complex plane and multiply it by $i$ we rotate it's position 90 degrees. I don't think that anyone would claim that "rotation by 90 degrees" is an imaginary concept.

Comment: Okay. Understood that point. Phew, it was like clearing up the mess in my mind. Thanks again!

Comment: As for why real numbers are not "real" well... there is some leaps in thinking that we have to overcome to think of real numbers as meaningful things... You know you have never stepped into $1$ [river](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Heraclitus). Every moment that you see the river it moves. And changes. When we talk in math about numbers we are somehow counting or measuring something which is not subject to the real world of space and time. The objects we are discussing do not move or change in time. They are somehow not of the real world.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! But, can you please explain what do you mean by "They are somehow not of real world"? Also, for the second last line, does this mean that every probability that we find is subject to change with respect of time? Thanks again.

Comment: Your first question: 
You may elect to think about these things with some more rigor if you'd like but I am not really the best resource for your study. This is taken on by the big philosophers. Namely, Plato talks about it in the Theaetetus.
Numbers are special in some sense. You can say there are 3 apples in the "physical world" but I am not sure that "3" is exactly in the physical world. 

Your second question: 
Yeah. That line of thought is [Bayesian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability).

Answer (score 4):

Your teacher's answer is perhaps slightly misleading, but not entirely mistaken.

If we restrict our focus to the real numbers, then the graph of $x^2+y^2=0$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by the point at the origin $\{ (0,0) \}$.

We can also factorise $x^2+y^2$ as $(x-yi)(x+yi)=0$, which is equal to zero if and only if $x-yi=0$ or $x+yi=0$. If the variables $x$ and $y$ are both real, this means that we must have $x=y=0$, since $x = \pm yi$ and $0$ is the only complex number that is both real and imaginary.

However, if $x$ and $y$ are allowed to range over $\mathbb{C}$, then $x-yi=0$ and $x+yi=0$ are both 'complex lines'. The word *line* here is slightly misleading because their dimension is $1$ over $\mathbb{C}$, not over $\mathbb{R}$.

The reason this seems counterintuitive is because we often view $\mathbb{C}$ as a *plane*—and indeed $\mathbb{C}$ is $2$-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$. But then $\mathbb{C}^2$ is $4$-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$, and then the equations $x-yi=0$ and $x+yi=0$ describe $2$-dimensional subspaces of a $4$-dimensional space. This is understandably difficult to intuit!

It is worth pointing out, also, that $x^2+y^2=0$ is the **union** of the complex lines $x-yi=0$ and $x+yi=0$, not their intersection.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But, I think to understand your answer in a complete I would have to study this topic in much more detail than we are expected to understand in Senior High School especially the second last para. But, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The conic $x^2+y^2=0$ in $\mathbf C^2$ splits into two lines since
$$x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)$$
so it's the union of the  *isotropic lines $y=ix$ and $y=-ix$. The point $(0,0)$ belongs to both lines.

*Note*: In complex projective geometry, the points at infinity on those lines, $(1:i:0)$ and $(1:-i:0)$ are called the *cyclic points*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your teacher was referring to the factorization

$$x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)=0 \iff x=iy \quad \lor \quad x=-iy$$

Comment: So the two brackets of RHS denote the imaginary line. But how do we plot them to show intersection?

Comment: @jayant98 If we assume $x$ and $y$ real then if $x=iy$ we obtain $iy=-iy \implies y=0$ and then $x=0$. In that sense we can say that $x=iy \quad \lor \quad x=-iy \implies x=0 \quad \land \quad y=0$ and then we can view that as the intersection of the two lines.